# Update div on AJAX submit jQuery is updating all divs

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to update a div with an ajax post.  Problem is...it's updating every div.

Here's the json.php:

```
//json.php

$data['months'] = $db->escape_value($_POST['check']);
$data['id'] = $db->escape_value($_POST['hidden']);


$query = "UPDATE month SET months = '{$data['months']}' WHERE monthID = '{$data['id']}'";
$result = $db->query($query);

if($result) {
  $data['success'] = true;
  $data['message'] = "Update Successful!";
  $data['text'] = $_POST['check'];
  echo json_encode($data);
} else {
  $data['message'] = "Update could not be completed.";
}
```

And the html:

```
<?php

$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM month');


?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>jQuery/Ajax - Update is updating all divs</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input.check, button.save, input.cancel, div.message").hide();

  $(".edit").click(function(){
      $(this).parent().siblings("li.liTwo").children("input.delete").hide();
      $(this).parent().siblings("li.liThree").children("button.save").show();
      $(this).parent().siblings("li.liFour").children("input.cancel").show();
      $(this).parents("ul").siblings("div.showText").hide();
      $(this).parents("ul").siblings("input.check").show();
      $(this).hide();
      return false;
    });

  $(".cancel").click(function(){
      $(this).parent().siblings("li.liTwo").children("input.delete").show();
      $(this).parent().siblings("li.liThree").children("button.save").hide();
      $(this).parent().siblings("li.liOne").children("input.edit").show();
      $(this).parents("ul").siblings("div.showText").show();
      $(this).parents("ul").siblings("input.check").hide();
      $(this).hide();
      return false;
    });


  $("form[name=form1]").submit(function(){
    var params = $(this);
    $.post("json.php", { hidden : $(this).find("[name=hidden]").val(), check :   $(this).find("[name=check]").val() },
      function (data){
        if(data.success) {
          $(".showText").html(data.text);
          $(".message").html(data.message).slideDown("fast");
          $(".check").hide();
          $("button.save").hide();
          $(".cancel").hide();
          $(".edit").show();
          $(".delete").show();
          $(".showText").show();
          return false;
        }
      }, "json");
    return false;
  });



});
</script>
 </head>
<body>
<div class="message">message</div>
    <?php while($row = $db->fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>
    <form action="json.php" name="form1" method="post">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="showText"><?php echo $row['months']; ?></div>
          <input name="check" type="text" class="check" value="<?php echo $row['months']; ?>" />
          <input name="hidden" type="hidden" class="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['monthID']; ?>" />
          <ul class="list">
            <li class="liOne">
              <input name="edit" type="button" class="edit" value="edit" />
            </li>
            <li class="liTwo">
              <input name="delete" type="submit" class="delete" value="delete" />
            </li>
            <li class="liThree">
              <button name="save" type="submit" class="save" value="<?php echo $row['monthID']; ?>">save</button>
            </li>
            <li class="liFour">
              <input name="cancel" type="button" class="cancel" value="cancel" />
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
<!--<a id="reset" href="test3.php">reset</a>--> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a context (the form) for the elements you're changing:

```
  $("form[name=form1]").submit(function(){
    var form = this;
    var params = $(this);
    $.post(form.action, { hidden : $(this).find("[name=hidden]").val(), check : $(this).find("[name=check]").val() },
      function (data){
        if(data.success) {
          $(".showText", form).html(data.text);
          $(".message", form).html(data.message).slideDown("fast");
          $(".check", form).hide();
          $("button.save", form).hide();
          $(".cancel", form).hide();
          $(".edit", form).show();
          $(".delete", form).show();
          $(".showText", form).show();
          return false;
        }
      }, "json");
    return false;
  });
```

Also, if you hide a parent element, the children are hidden, too, so you probably want to do that...

Answer (score 1):

Every div has the same class: showText. They need unique IDs instead, like Div1, Div2. Then update them by their ID: $("#Div1")

Comment: I'm pulling values from a database...so ID's won't work for me.

Comment: How does the database keep them separate?

Comment: When you update the database, what are you using for the WHERE clause? Don't they have unique identifiers in the DB?

Comment: Yeah..there's a hidden field that passes the ID on post.  The update isn't a problem...I just cant' get the new value to display on it's respective div...correction:  it does display, only it shows up on every div.  I've struggled with this for hours.

Comment: okay, restructure the HTML that is generated. Add an id attribute to each element, and make it the same as the hidden id you are talking about. Then when you set the value use $("#yourhiddenid") to select the element instead of $(".showText")

Answer (score 1):

Hint, instead of answer:

How many elements does $(".showText") return?

2nd Hint: It's more than one!

===

Edit for more clarity:

The first issue is that you're selecting by classes like .showText.  But you're creating multiple forms, each of which has an element that matches .showText.  You need some way to point at the right element in each form.  One way to solve this is to add an ID on each FORM tag, so you can then select things like $('#form-number-$N .showtext) -- which selects any elements with class="showtext" inside the element with id "#form-number-$N"

You're looping over rows in your database and writing the forms.  So you need some *variable* data to identify each individual form.

You've got a while loop that populates $row:

```
<?php while($row = $db->fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>
```

But currently, every form you create has a name attribute of "form1".

So what if, instead of:

```
 <?php while($row = $db->fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>
 <form action="json.php" name="form1" method="post">
```

You did something like:

```
 <?php while($row = $db->fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>
 <form action="json.php" name="form<?PHP echo $row['id']; ?>" id="<?PHP echo $row['id']; ?> class="myFormClass" method="post">
```

Then you could use a handler that looks something like:

```
  $("form.myFormClass").submit(function(){
    var params = $(this);
    $.post("json.php", { hidden : $(this).find("[name=hidden]").val(), check :   $(this).find("[name=check]").val() },
      function (data){
        if(data.success) {
          $(this.id + " .showText").html(data.text);
```

...
              return false;
            }
          }, "json");
        return false;
      });

Do you see what's happening there?

Comment: Geez...why oh why do these forums have to be sooooo condescending?

Comment: Not being condescending... just thought you'd see it quickly.  Editing for more clarity.

Comment: Meant no harm...all apologies. Just frustrated..grr.

Comment: okay, see my updated answer, and think it through. The key error you're making is that you're trying to use the same handler on each form.  You need to devise a way to reference the appropriate form.  My updates show you how to add an ID to each form, and then reference that ID in your handler.  I'm not just going to fix it for you to copy paste (I'm very tired, and a little sick, otherwise I might), but I think I've given you enough direction to figure it out.  If you're really burned out, take a break, and re-read the answers here when you get back.

Comment: Tim...It still won't work.  I'm assuming the ID sent with form is "monthID" instead of "id"...right?

Comment: I appreciate the help though...hope you feel better.  I think you may have given me enough to muck around with.  You're right...I think it's time for a break.